# How can I build a custom template for joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I have knowledge of wordpress and learning now joomla but i can't understand it below some queries are in my mind so please solve it someone.

**1** - Already i have ready index.php with static html , but i can't understand how to become it dynamic please someone give me idea about this.

**2** - How can i get an article in looping format like wordpress?.

**3**  - How can i get banners in slider?.

Comment: Please look at how the default Joomla template works, you'll get a better idea. Maybe be an idea to ask your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com), which is the dedicated SE network for Joomla related querstions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand how joomla! works, then you need to understand how templates works, in this way you can properly create the solution you need. Check this info:

- **Begginers Guide:**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Beginners
- **Understanding Joomla! templates:**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Joomla!_templates
- **Creating a basic Joomla! template:**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template
- **More advanced Joomla! templates:**
  https://docs.joomla.org/More_advanced_Joomla!_templates
- In joomla! you can use an extension for the slider, find many options in the [extensions directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/photos-a-images/slideshow).

Extra, by default joomla! includes [Bootstrap v2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/), so you can use the code in this library or
 you can include other library or framework.